# How to Integrate OpenCV_2.4.6 with bloodshed dev C++?

Tags: opencv, integration, dev-c++

I googled this question a lot but couldn't find any solution? Please help.I found help for OpenCV 2.0 and 2.1 but that doesn't work for the latest version 2.4.6. Also I have no idea what CMake and MingW is?

Comment: You should write which OS You are trying to install it on.

As for CMake and MingW, please show some effort and read about what they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html#table-of-content-introduction) is an official installation guide. You should not use dev-c++ because it is old, outdated software. Try some modern IDE like code::blocks or eclipse.

Comment: Had anyone told me that before,, I would have saved a lot of time,,, finally going to change IDE,, Thanks :-),

Comment: Please note that a reboot of Dev-C++ itself has been updated too, and is as modern as its competitors are: https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/